# How to force a url to open through IE 11 from custom button

Tags: apex

I came cross the below issue and I hope you can suggest if there is any possible way to this.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F0000000kBTGIA2

Please look over it and let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: That would be a huge security vulnerability if any browser could do what you ask.

Answer (score 3):

You can't force a specific application to run on a computer from the Internet. Browsers will naturally open new tabs and/or windows in themselves, since they know how to handle such resources without the OS's involvement, and there's no standard that specifies that such a feature should be available.